# i have to do login form validation,if password match it will move forward

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
it is moving forward on any user name or password.let me know the correct solution for this.
```

this is my dao.java class

```
public List < Student > getLogin() {
  return template.query("select * from auction", new RowMapper < Student > () {

    @Override
    public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
      Student s = new Student();
      s.setName(rs.getString(1))
      s.setPassword(rs.getString(2));

      return s;
    }
  });
}
```

this is my controller.java kindly correct my code....what kind of changes i need to do

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addLogin",method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String addLogin(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student s, Model model) { 
  List<Student> list=dao.getLogin(); 
  List <Student> b=dao.getStudentRecord(); 
  String name=s.getName(); 
  String password=s.getPassword(); 
  if(name.equals(list) && password.equals(list)) { 
    model.addAttribute("welcome",name); 
    model.addAttribute("record",b); 
    return "change"; 
  } else { 
    model.addAttribute("login","Wrong Username or Password"); 
    return "login"; 
  }
}
```

Comment: This may help https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: but it all about size and space validation...i want to check my password which is stored in a database with prompt password by user...

Comment: if both are same then only it will move forward...this my condition..plz help

Comment: Use javascript to add new password field on html page. And check if typed passwords are equal when user submits form

Comment: ok...shall i use jsp page instead of html page?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to query all users to do a login. instead change the query to

```
"select * from auction where userName=? and password=?"
```

in the service check whether the query returned any row. if the query returned a row then login success otherwise login failed.

So the Spring Implementation becomes..

```
template.queryForList("select * from auction where userName=? and password=?", new Object[]{userName, password});
```

Comment: then what kind of changes i need to do at controller side?

Comment: thanks..i got the ans from ur reference..i will try it...also explained in https://dzone.com/articles/spring-mvc-example-for-user-registration-and-login-1

Comment: public Student validateUser(Student s) {
      String sql = "select * from auction where name='" + s.getName() + "' and password='" + s.getPassword()
      + "'";
      List<Student> list = template.query(sql, new StudentMapper());
      return list.size() > 0 ? list.get(0) : null;
      }
}
class StudentMapper implements RowMapper<Student> {
   public Student mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
     Student s = new Student();
     s.setName(rs.getString("name"));
     s.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
     return s;
   }
}

Comment: here is my controller......@RequestMapping(value = "/addLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView loginProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
   @ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Student s) {
     ModelAndView mav = null;
     Student u = dao.validateUser(s);
     if (null != u) {
     mav = new ModelAndView("change");
     mav.addObject("welcome", u.getName());
     return mav;
     } else {
     mav = new ModelAndView("login");
     mav.addObject("login", "Username or Password is wrong!!");
     return mav;
     }
     
   }

Comment: plz let me know...where i am making mistake??